# Eevee issue: Foreground plane mysteriously eclipsed by plane behind it when rendered

Tags: texturing, objects, eevee-render-engine

I've run across a strange Eevee issue where a plane in the background appears in front of a foreground plane when rendered. Not an issue when rendered with Cycles. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.4.1, Windows 11

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Alpha Blend mode with Eevee: [Wrong Draw Order with Alpha Blend in Eevee](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/66334) - you can read there that the ordering of alpha blended objects depends on their origins.

In terms of solutions there's a few options.

If you can make the material's Blend Mode: Opaque, and that will resolve the issue:
[image: Material Opaque blend mode]

Alternatively you can try changing the material to use a different Blend Mode like *Alpha hashed*.

Lastly, if that does not work, another workaround would be to separate out your meshes into separate objects, and then ensure their origin points are ordered nearest-to-furthest to ensure the alpha blend ordering is correct.